# Entity Framework CTP5 - Reading Multiple Record Sets From a Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-ctp5, multiple-resultsets

In EF4, this was not easily possible. You either had to degrade to classic ADO.NET (DataReader), use **[ObjectContext.Translate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384.aspx)** or use the **EFExtensions** project.

Has this been implemented off the shelf  in EF CTP5?

If not, what is the recommended way of doing this?

Do we have to cast the `DbContext<T>` as an `IObjectContextAdapter` and access the underlying `ObjectContext` in order to get to this method?

Can someone point me to a good article on doing this with EF CTP5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So i got this working, here's what i have:

```
internal SomeInternalPOCOWrapper FindXXX(string xxx)
{
    Condition.Requires(xxx).IsNotNullOrEmpty();

    var someInternalPokey = new SomeInternalPOCOWrapper();
    var ctx = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

    var con = new SqlConnection("xxxxx");
    {
        con.Open();
        DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "exec dbo.usp_XXX @xxxx";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("xxxx", xxx));

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // -- RESULT SET #1
            someInternalPokey.Prop1 = ctx.Translate<InternalPoco1>(rdr);

            // -- RESULT SET #2
            rdr.NextResult();
            someInternalPokey.Prop2 = ctx.Translate<InternalPoco2>(rdr);

            // -- RESULT SET #3
            rdr.NextResult();
            someInternalPokey.Prop3 = ctx.Translate<InternalPoco3>(rdr);

            // RESULT SET #4
            rdr.NextResult();
            someInternalPokey.Prop4 = ctx.Translate<InternalPoco4>(rdr);
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    return someInternalPokey;
}
```

Essentially, it's basically like classic ADO.NET. You read the `DbReader`, advance to the next result set, etc.

But at least we have the `Translate` method which seemingly does a left-to-right between the result set fields and the supplied entity.

Note the method is internal.

My Repository calls this method, then **hydrates** the DTO into my domain objects.

I'm not 100% happy with it for 3 reasons:

1. We have to cast the `DbContext` as `IObjectContextAdapter`. The method `Translate` should be on `DbContext<T>` class IMO.
2. We have to use classic ADO.NET Objects. Why? Stored Procedures are a **must have** for any ORM. My main gripe with EF is the lack of the stored procedure support and this seems to not have been rectified with EF CTP5.
3. You have to open a new SqlConnection. Why can't it use the same connection as the one opened by the EF Context?

Hope this both helps someone and sends out a message to the EF team. We need multiple result support for SPROCS off the shelf. You can map a stored proc to a complex type, so why can't we map a stored proc to *multiple complex types*?

Comment: The .Translate method is very picky as well.           "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyPoco'. 
A member of the type (some data type here) does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."