# how to use stored procedures in entity framework which return multiple recordsets

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I want to build few stored procedures which will be returning multiple recordsets. I want to know, how can I use them in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support multiple result sets currently but the support is already [included in EF June 2011 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure.aspx) (it is first CTP of upcoming EF 4.2).

If you want to have stored procedures with multiple result sets in EF 4 or EF 3.5 you can check [EFExtensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Entity Framework can't handle multiple recordsets from a stored procedure.

If you need multiple record sets, you'll have to drop back to class ADO.NET and map the different DataTables by hand.

If you're willing to jump into a CTP version of Entity Framework, you could attempt to use the method found here:

[Entity Framework CTP5 - Reading Multiple Record Sets From a Stored Procedure - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253328/entity-framework-ctp5-reading-multiple-record-sets-from-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Hmm .. that solution is not great too. Since we ave to open another connection in any ways. By the way is it recommended to have a SP returning multiple recordsets? or we should build separate ones?

Comment: @eFriend - Personally, I always write separate procedures in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Having run into this issue myself, the only way around it was to either split the sprocs or fall back to classic ADO.Net as suggested. I my case splitting the sprocs was the route that we used.